# Identify instances where string exists more than once in a row + Python, Pandas, Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, lambda

I'm want to write a script that will identify instances where a word (string) appears in a row of a pandas dataframe more than once.

Using a lambda function I can identify the existence of a string in a row but but I can't find any information on how to identify '2 or more' instances of the string, this is an example of what I have currently:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],'Ans1':['Yes','Yes','Yes'],'Ans2':['No','Yes','No'],'Ans3':['No','No','No']})
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('Yes').any(), axis=1)

df
```

Pseudocode for what I'm trying to get:

```
if 'Yes' isin row > 1:
   df['Results'] == True
```

Desired result:

```
ID  Ans1    Ans2    Ans3    Result
1   Yes     No      No      False
2   Yes     Yes     No      True
3   Yes     No      No      False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try, you can do column filtering if you don't want to check the entire dataframe for yes, then use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), equals to, and `sum` with axis=1 to sum values along rows then check to see if that sum is [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html?highlight=gt#pandas-dataframe-gt), greater than, 1:

```
df['Result'] = df.eq('Yes').sum(1).gt(1)
```

Output:

```
   ID Ans1 Ans2 Ans3  Result
0   1  Yes   No   No   False
1   2  Yes  Yes   No    True
2   3  Yes   No   No   False
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```py
df['Result'] = df[df == 'Yes'].count(axis=1).gt(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick for your specific case. It quite literally implements your pseudocode to every row.

```
def check_row(row):
    count = 0
    for i in row:
        if i == 'Yes':
            count += 1
    if count > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
df['Results'] = df.apply(check_row, axis=1)
```

Comment: Eww!  This is wrong and anti-pandas.   I would not recommend this at all.

Comment: Agree... I'm tempted to downvote but presumably it works so I'll give a by ball.

Comment: That's fair. After seeing your result, I understand why one would consider my result inefficient and anti-pandas. I didn't have the knowledge of pandas that you do. However, I still got an accurate result. Glad to learn for the future!

Comment: Well, you are right, it probably technical "wrong", just not the proper way to do calcuation on a pandas dataframe.

Comment: That's fair, appreciate the criticism. I will keep that formula in mind for future problems. I was just trying to help with the tools I had knowledge of at the time. I had not yet seen your answer, and figured a "right" answer was better than no answer at all.